# Is there an igraph function in Python for returning the indexes of shortest_path results

Tags: python, igraph, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph which I know has a valid shortest path for a specific set of points (e.g. 105 and 149).

I am not sure how to interpret the results to get the indexes for the nodes that are traversed by the shortest_paths function.

If a path starting at 105 passes through: 117, 123, 29, 35, 56, 78 and terminates at 149. How do I retrieve the array of indices [117, 123, 29, 35, 56, 78]?

My code something like this:

```
path = G.shortest_paths(source=[G.vs[105]], target=[G.vs[149]], mode='all')
```

My `path` object returns an array with like `[[6]]`.

Comment: You can read more about how to use shortest paths on this [TowardsDataScience tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/newbies-guide-to-python-igraph-4e51689c35b4)

Comment: Thank you, maybe it was just me, but I misunderstood the difference between: `shortest_paths`, `get_shortest_paths` and `get_all_shortest_paths`

Comment: In some future version of igraph, `shortest_paths` may get renamed to something more intuitive, such as `distances`, eliminating this confusion. Feedback like this is always welcome, and I encourage you to post about your experiences with learning igraph on https://igraph.discourse.group/

Comment: There are many ways to [contribute to the project](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-this-project), and giving such feedback is one way.

Comment: I think we should learn a lot from `networkx` package because it's documented very well. They implemented shortest paths in quite a similar way: `nx.shortest_path(G, source=0, target=4)`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for feedback. I use `igraph` while working with big data and I need to solve some issues in order to make it work in conjunction with `numpy`. I will share my notes in the future for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `igraph.shortest_paths` is not designed for this kind of usage. Try
`igraph.get_all_shortest_paths` instead:

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph(n=5, edges=[(0,1), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5) , (3,5), (4,6), (6, 0)], directed=False)
path = g.get_all_shortest_paths(0, to=2)
>>> path
[[0, 1, 4, 2], [0, 6, 4, 2]]
>>> [p[1:-1] for p in path]
[[1, 4], [6, 4]]
```